# How to change the cell content of all cells matching a greple command using mgsub in r?

Tags: r

I am trying to subset a df where I first pull all rows matching two separate conditions (mutually exclusive), then rename all cells based on those two conditions, and finally shove them in a new df.

```
df1
   a           b
1  vh          99
2  cd;hum;ps   89
3  vh;thr      102
4  pd;vh       67
5  pd;wdr      84
```

Then make some categories:

```
onlyag <- subset(df, !grepl("hum|os|pa|comp|cd|ps|adl|ad|wdr|tc|apg|sub", con.tac))
onlyneg <- subset(df, !grepl("atp|pur|vh|thr|pi|ato|pd", con.tac))
```

Onlyag contains only: atp|pur|vh|thr|pi|ato

Onlyneg contains only: hum|os|pa|comp|cd|ps|adl|ad|wdr|tc|apg|sub|pd

Code attempted for desired result

```
df2 <- mgsub::mgsub(df$a, c(onlyag, onlyneg), c("onlyag", "onlyneg"))

df2 <- mgsub::mgsub(df$a, c(!grepl ("hum|os|pa|comp|cd|ps|adl|ad|wdr|tc|apg|sub", con.tac), !grepl("atp|pur|vh|thr|pi|ato|pd", con.tac)), c("onlyag", "onlyneg"))
```

Desired result:

```
   a           b
1  onlyag      99
2  onlyneg     89
3  onlyag      102
4  onlyneg     67
5  onlyneg     84
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below should do the trick. It uses str_detect from the tidyverse stringr package, as well as case_when to set up rules for when to label "onlyag" or "onlyneg". The exclamation point right before str_detect flips the statement from FALSE to TRUE, and vice versa, which I believe is what you're looking for based on your use of !grepl in the sample code.

The TRUE statement at the end essentially says that for all cases where the values in onlyag_vector or onlyneg_vector aren't found, put in "neither".

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df1 <- data.frame("a" = c("vh",
                          "cd;hum;ps",
                          "vh;thr",
                          "pd;vh",
                          "pd;wdr"),
                  "b" = c(99,
                          89,
                          102,
                          67,
                          84))
df1

onlyag_vector <- "hum|os|pa|comp|cd|ps|adl|ad|wdr|tc|apg|sub"
onlyneg_vector <- "atp|pur|vh|thr|pi|ato|pd"

df1 %>% 
  mutate(a = case_when(!str_detect(a, onlyag_vector) ~ "onlyag",
                       !str_detect(a, onlyneg_vector) ~ "onlyneg",
                        TRUE ~ "neither"))
```